# Proving a predicate does not imply another predicate.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Suppose we have arbitrary predicates are $P$ and $Q$.

Let the statements be defined as follows:

$F1:$ [for all x, P(x)] is false OR [for some x, Q(x)] is true

$F2:$ [for some x, P(x)] is false OR [for all x, Q(x)] is true

Prove that $F1 \neq\implies F2$ (does not apply)

We have to simply create a $P$ and $Q$ so that $P$ and $Q$ satisfy $F1$,  but falsify $F2$.

---

Let $domain=\mathbb{N}$

Let $P(x):$

Let $Q(y):$

What is the easiest counter example?

Comment: $P(x)=Q(x)="x=0"$

Comment: @Bettybel how exactly did you come up with that?

Comment: I just took the easiest example I could think.

Comment: Why do not use the corerct symbols ? $\lnot \forall x \ P(x)$ for "[for all x, P(x)] is false", $\nvDash$ instead of $≠⟹$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

> $(x=0)$ as $P(x)$ and $(x > 0)$ as $Q(x)$.

Thus, we have:

> $\mathbb N \vDash \lnot \forall x \ (x=0) \lor \exists x \ (x > 0)$

but:

> $\mathbb N \nvDash \lnot \exists x \ (x=0) \lor \forall x \ (x > 0)$

and thus the first formula does not *logically implies* the second one.

Comment: You are considering 0 a natural number in this case right?

Comment: @KSplitX - YES.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing using sets instead of properties, on your domain $\mathbb{N}$:

F1: $P\neq \mathbb{N}$ OR $Q\neq \emptyset$

F2: $P=\emptyset$ OR $Q=\mathbb{N}$

Can you find a counterexample to $F1 \implies F2$, i.e. a way to make $F1$ true but $F2$ false?